# Android: Is it better to declare ImageView or Buttons programatically or i can just use it from the XML file?

Tags: android, xml

I am finalizing my chess project and I have done all the things dynamically in the code, like this:

```java
two_player = new ImageView(ctx);
two_player.setImageResource(R.drawable.twoplayers);
```

I know I can also do it in the xml file and just find it like this:

```java
ImageView twoplayer = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.twoplayer);
```

I am confused which one is faster: dynamically defining or the xml file calling?

Comment: It is best to keep static elements in the XML file and dynamically created elements in the Java file.

Comment: Thanks for responding.. :) but what about the chess pieces?? i am saying, i can declare it in xml, still in its onClickListner i can change its LayoutParams

Answer (score 1, accepted):

of course inflating from xml is slower in run-time but **much** faster in code-writing-time ;)

Comment: @Niraj - i have defined a function that reassign all the chess pieces back to normal.. :) anyways, thanks alot :) Now i don't have to change my whole code :P ;)